# How to create a table with switching tab content?

Tags: html

I want to make a table looks like this:
[image]

The inside table is not an issue but don't know how to create the outer frame which includes "Item Descriptions", "Shipping", and "Returns" tabs. A minimal example would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could certainly use jQuery to solve this.  That's what I did when I needed some tabs.  I did something like:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#tab-description">Description</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-shipping">Shipping</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-returns">Returns</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-description" class="mytabs">
</div>
<div id="tab-shipping" class="mytabs">
</div>
<div id="tab-returns" class="mytabs">
</div>
```

and then some jQuery to make the tabs:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#mytabs").tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle'} });
   });
</script>
```

works pretty nicely for me.  Just fill in whatever your content is in each of the divs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder if I put it in to Ebay, how do I get JQuery though?

Comment: @itsmatt: Couldn't get the script run for some reasons. I added it to my `<head>`, but it didn't change items into tabs.

Comment: @Chan - do you have jquery?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ has a demo and you can also get the jquery ui stuff there.

Comment: @itsmatt: Thank you. I'm new to web stuff so I think I'd better play around with it a bit.

Comment: @itsmatt This looks good except nothing was turned into tabs with the HTML and JavaScript shown. Just remains a UL. Also, the jQuery is selecting the id `$('#mytabs')` but there isn't an element with that id. There's classes so should it be `$('.mytabs')`?

Answer (score 3):

People usually call those tabs. You can find an example in [this link](http://clagnut.com/sandbox/csstabs/?writingtext=csstabs).