# Is there any way to include tabs within a row in a table?

Tags: php, html, css

For example I am trying to build this:
[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udxkH.png)

I am fetching data from mysql database and showing the information using while loop.

I can build it to look something like above however, when clicked on a tab on any of those table, the tab on the first table open. Any suggestions or idea would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would have to show your code what you have tried to make it possible for us to help. We don't know if there is something like bootstrap.js or jquery involved, nor do we see the html structure,...

Answer (score 0):

Please look at what you're asking for here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

Essentially, the use of JS or Jquery will be needed, trust me, it'll be a lot simpler doing so.

Instead of adding a paragraph tag, you can use a div tag and insert your PHP there like this:

```
<div class= 'tab one'>

<?php
 //insert php code here showing the table..
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However putting that in a while loop would not work. I am trying to get tabs like the ones [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs) for every row on a column from my database table.

Comment: please check here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114180/how-to-create-a-table-with-switching-tab-content , all you would have to do is make sure you import only a single row each time (SELECT row1 FROM table)