# Extract information from a tabbed table in HTML using PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, tabs, extract

I started out trying to use PowerShell to grab data from a web page. I learned how to extract tables and used that info to get [portfolio data](http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=ANWPX&region=usa&culture=en-US) for a particular mutual fund. This was fairly simple with help from the [internet](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2015/01/05/extracting-tables-from-powershells-invoke-webrequest/).

```
$url = 'http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=ANWPX&region=usa&culture=en-US'
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$tables = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

After further digging I easily found the data I was looking for:

```
$tables[1].rows[4].cells[1].innerText.Trim()
US Stock

$tables[1].rows[4].cells[2].innerText.Trim()
52.27
```

My problem that I can't seem to find an answer to on the web is this: how do I get a table that is embedded within a group of *tabbed* tables. An example is [here](http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/performance-return.action?t=ANWPX&region=usa&culture=en-US). Under the **Trailing Total Returns** heading halfway down the page, I want the 15-Year return for ANWPX (which is 8.82). PowerShell tells me there are 0 tables in the collection when I use the same method as above (even though it's obvious there are tables on the web page).

It appears the table I want is going to be harder to get at with PowerShell when it's grouped together with other tables in *tabbed* format. I'm struggling figuring out how to get that data into an object in PowerShell.

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I know virtually nothing about HTML, (or [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114180/how-to-create-a-table-with-switching-tab-content), if that's what we're dealing with???), but any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this page is doing some tricky JavaScript to load the page. The URL you want is:

```
$url = 'http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/fund/trailing-total-returns.action?&t=XNAS:ANWPX&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&s=0P00001MJB&ndec=2&ep=true&align=d&annlz=true&comparisonRemove=false&loccat=&taxadj=&benchmarkSecId=&benchmarktype='
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$tables[0].rows[1].cells[10].innerText.Trim()
```

Output:

```
8.82
```

I found this by just monitoring the network using Chrome when the page was loading.

[image: Picture of Chrome network inspector]